# Prestashop zero tax on product if product group and user have vat number

Tags: php, prestashop

can anybody now which class i need modify when I need condition if product group id 5 and customer address has vat number, on this product group will be applied 0% tax?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to interact with the

```
/classes/tax/TaxCalculator.php
```

file.

Especially you'll need to override the costruct to return the expected taxes array based on your needs.